# Need to select a drop down list element with a particular attribute value from a list of drop down lists and set its selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

`.FilterList` is the class name of all the drop down lists

```
var $lists = $('.FilterList[ctype="' + ctype + '"]').css('display', 'inline');
```

Something like the below works fine but I was wondering if there's a more concise and efficient method
I could use instead of the `.each()`

```
 $lists.each(function () { $(this).attr('filterid') == filterid ? $(this).val(thisval) : null; });
```

Whilst I am after something more like:

```
$lists.first('.FilterList[filterid = "' + filterid + '"]').val(thisval);
```

Comment: you mean an alternative for `each` function?

Comment: yes, an alternative to the .each() that would work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague without any HTML to demonstrate what you're trying to grab from the DOM, but from what I gather, it seems like something like this should work:

```
$lists.find("[filterid='" + filterId + "']").val(myVal);
```

Honestly, though, I'm just guessing at what it is you are looking for. Try creating a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to give us a better idea of what you're after.